# Error #Name? in access form with DLookup

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, jet

I have the error `#Name?` in a form in Access 2013 in a textbox that have as origin a DlookUp function.
Specifically I need to do the same thing that is on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666775/how-to-update-a-field-with-information-from-a-table-based-on-another-fields-opti) topic: automatically update the field `Costo Unitario` field based on the selection of the field `Operatore`

[image]

The combobox of the `Operatore` field takes the values from a table named `Operatori` that it is like that:

```
Operatore        CostoOp_Unitario
---------        --------
Marco             20,07
Giuseppe          20,02
Gennaro           19,69
Pierangelo        17,05
```

The function that is set up as `Control Source` for the textbox that gives the `#Name?` error is:

```
=DLookUp([CostoOp_Unitario];[Operatori];"[Operatore]=""" & [OperatoreComboBox].[Text] & """")
```

based on the function that is present in the thread that I linked above. `OperatoreComboBox` is the combobox `Operatore` in the image. Why it outputs this error?

Answer (score 2):

I think your syntax is not correct. Try this one:

```
=DLookUp("[CostoOp_Unitario]","Operatori","[Operatore] = '" & [OperatoreComboBox] & "'")
```

Comment: It gives a "syntax error" when I try to insert this function